# Different ways languages use adjectives as arguments?

Tags: syntax

I'm not sure how to word this. I'm not talking about languages where adjectives can act as nouns on their own. I'm talking about when 'states' are used as arguments.

An example in this is the phrase; She wants to see him dead. Here, 'dead' isn't a noun, but has its adjectival meaning. Here the phrase means 'she' wants to see 'him' while he is dead. This structure comes up more often with the verb 'make'. As in 'to make something dead' (a euphemism for 'to kill'), or 'to make pretty', 'to make someone mad', you get the idea.

English handles this by simply placing an adjective after the direct object. This violates English's normal noun phrase order, so this clearly marks them as not being part of the same noun phrase.

I'm curious to know how other languages may handle such a structure. English's system clearly wouldn't work so well in languages with freer noun phrase orders. Maybe some languages instead make such phrases via incorporation of some kind? I was thinking adverbial clauses may also work, though they could result in ambiguity. In the phrase 'Billy wants to see Bob while he's dead', which does 'he' refer to? Does Billy want this event to occur while he's dead, or does he want it to occur when Bob's dead? Context may make it obvious here, granted, but this doesn't work with certain other phrases I'd rather not say (most such constructions are rather dark).

Is there a name for such constructions? What other strategies may languages use?